# Single Mocha tests output

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm looking for a way to provide a single boolean output from my mocha tests instead of the standard test list. If all tests passed - it should return true, otherwise false. It's fine if it's written in a separate file on a server, we don't even need to suppress the logs, but I couldn't find a way to use the after() function to get a list of all tests that had been run and their results.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to use the process exit code. A non-zero exit code means a failure and zero means all pass.

Comment: Good idea, thank you! I actually solved this by using the this.currentTest object in the afterEach function and collecting the results in an array, which I write to a file in the after function.